Sitecore GraphQL get siblings
I need to build a tree structure

Get the parents (I can do that using either parent/ancestors)
Children (use children - but it gets just one level down)
Descendants(How do I do this?)
Siblings (How do I do this?)

eg.
Root
 Parent 1
  - Child 1.1
  - Child 1.2
    - Child 1.2.1
      - Child 1.2.1.1
 Parent 2
  - Child 2.1
  - Child 2.2


To get the siblings you can use get parent, then their parent children using the following query:


query {
  item(path: "/sitecore/content/Demo/Demo/Home/Test", language: "en") {
    ...siblings
    name
  }
}
fragment siblings on Item {
  parent {
    children {
      results {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}



Currently, it's NOT possible to retrieve all descendants due to GraphQL's limitation on recursive references within fragments, as discussed here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/929. (Because fragments within fragments could fix this - children within children)
As a workaround, and to ensure good performance, it's better to retrieve a fixed depth (e.g., 1-2-3 levels) of children. This approach helps you avoid exceeding GraphQL's complexity limitations and allows for better control over the performance in your code. This solution is more efficient than how Axes.GetDescendants() worked in the past, which was not optimal.
Example of 3 level of children (I have not included the pagination, so this would return the default 10 items, you can introduce pagination to this, to do this check: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/query-examples-for-the-delivery-api.html#get-items-filtered-by-multiple-paths):


query {
  item(
    path: "/sitecore/content/Demo/Demo/Home"
    language: "en"
  ) {
    ...descendants
  }
}
fragment descendants on Item {
  name
  firstLevel: children {
    results {
      name
      secondLevel: children {
        results {
          name
          thirdLevel: children {
            results {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



